# using RIGHT to get data from column and update to add result to new column

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a trouble to get this right.
I get data with this query

```
Select RIGHT(RTRIM(Nimi), 3) Riik from TABLE
```

But when I use this in update, then it has more then one result to insert.

So when I use it like this :

```
update #temp_table 
set veerg2 = (Select RIGHT(RTRIM(nimi), 3) nimi2 
from #temp_table a 
where a.nimi is not NULL )
```

Then I get error on that, but I need to get these three last chars into new column.

Need help on that.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax looks like SQL Server.  The correct query is most likely:

```
update a
    set veerg2 = RIGHT(RTRIM(nimi), 3)  
    from #temp_table a 
    where a.nimi is not NULL ;
```

The two changes are:

- The *table alias* defined in the `from` clause is used in the `update` rather than the table name.
- The `select` is removed from the `set`.  It is unnecessary.

You can also write this without the `from`:

```
update #temp_table
    set veerg2 = RIGHT(RTRIM(nimi), 3)  
    where nimi is not NULL ;
```